# How to animate separate objects without messing with their orientation?

Tags: animation

I made a quick axe model, but when I want to animate it, and insert keyframes for location and rotation.  It seems the model gets all centered at the location and rotation of the first object I clicked on.  I'd rather not have to join all the objects together, is there another way?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: By default the 2 objects should not share the same action if you've keyframed them together, but if you've given the same action to both the 2 objects, the location keyframes will take their origin into account. To fix that you could remove the action for the head and parent it to the handle

Comment: if you are a beginner (although moonboots is totally right, but beginners could have problems understanding that) - just parent all parts to an empty, which you can locate where ever you want to rotate around. Then only animate that empty.